# Error handling in non-throwing function in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am having problems with handling errors in non-throwing functions like overridden methods, delegate methods or dataSource methods. I only came up with logging the error and as you know this is not a good error-handling strategy. Is there any other way, approach etc.? Thank you.

EDIT:

```
enum SomethingError : Error{
    case somethingFailed
}

var anObject : AnObject?

........
........


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell throws{
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)

      guard let anObject = anObject else{
            throw SomethingError.somethingFailed
            //and maybe return unprocessed cell but you cannot return anything after "throw", or you cannot "throw" after "return"
        }

      .....
      .....

      return cell
}
```

You cannot do something like this, since :collectionView:cellForItemAt:indexPath is not a throwing function and it must return a cell. How can I catch an error here? This is the question. Only via logging?

EDIT: I know that I can use `if let` but **I want to catch/throw; HANDLE** an error here.

Comment: A concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: Define "error" since it's not throwing one? Do you have example of methods?

Comment: You **cannot** `throw` an error in `cellForItem` but you can `catch` thrown errors. Basically avoid any code in the delegate and datasource methods which can exit the scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can't propagate errors in implementations of protocols that don't explicitly require them.

You can `throw/catch` them in the same implementation or simply call a method to handle the error. In your example you can use `throw/catch` like this:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell throws{
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)

      do {

          guard let anObject = anObject else {
              throw SomethingError.somethingFailed
              //and maybe return unprocessed cell but you cannot return anything after "throw", or you cannot "throw" after "return"
      } catch SomethingError.somethingFailed {
          // handle the error here
      }

      .....
      .....

      return cell
}
```

And with just a function it will be something like this:

```
func handleError() {
    // handle error
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell throws{
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)

      guard let anObject = anObject else{
            handleError()
            return
        }

      .....
      .....

      return cell
}
```

For more information about error-handling in swift you can read: [The Swift Programming Language: Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)